# How to populate a dictionary of lists using comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

From this source list of dictionaries:

```
s = [ {'I':1}, {'I':2}, {'R':29}, {'R':33} ]
```

I want to create this dictionary, d:

```
{ 'I':[1,2], 'R':[29,33] }
```

And I can do it with what seems rather clumsy to me:

```
d = {'I':[], 'R':[]}
for i in s:
    for k,v in i.items():
        d[k].append(v)
```

It gets the job done, but I feel like I should be doing this with a comprehension of some sort.  Right?

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine.  clear and clean...

Comment: `{k: [vv for d in s for kk, vv in d.items() if kk == k] for k in {k for d in s for k in d}}` but don't do that. Your solution is fine.

Comment: See my approach below, however I totally agree with @DanielHao

Comment: Do your dicts always have just one item?

Comment: And if yes, are they always sorted by key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {}
for k in ['I', 'R']:
    d[k] = [d_[k] for d_ in s if k in d_]
```

if you don't want to hardcode the list of keys to iterate over, you can determine them in advance, e.g. by replacing

```
['I', 'R']
```

with

```
set([list(d_.keys())[0] for d_ in s])
```

Comment: It's the *closet* to what OP wants, but it's assumed the keys are known ahead of time. +1

Comment: @DanielHao good point. added that to my answer.

Comment: Bit shorter way to collect the keys: `{k for k, in s}`

Comment: Hey thanks!  The list comprehension makes sense to me and, yes, the source keys are known in advance. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine to me. One way of doing it without knowing the keys present in `s` beforehand:

```py
s = [ {'I':1}, {'I':2}, {'R':29}, {'R':33} ]

res = {}
for d in s:
    for k in d:
        res[k] = (res.get(k) or []) + [d[k]]

print(res)
```

Alternatively, this version might be a bit more efficient:

```
res[k] = res[k] + [d[k]] if k in res else [d[k]]
```

Output:

```py
{'I': [1, 2], 'R': [29, 33]}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, though the keys are known in advance in my particular case.